# Using classes from \Magento\Setup namespace in custom module

Tags: magento2

This is for Magento 2.4.13-p3, on PHP 7.4.

I'm working on a custom console command class. It uses another custom class named `Analyzer` in its constructor. I'm trying to inject a `Magento\Setup\Model\InstallerFactory` dependency into the Analyzer class constructor, and it doesn't work:

```
<?php

namespace Utpc\Explainer\Model;

use Magento\Setup\Model\InstallerFactory;

class Analyzer {

    protected InstallerFactory $installerFactory;

    public function __construct(
        InstallerFactory $installerFactory
    ) {
        $this->installerFactory = $installerFactory;
    }

    // etc....
```

With that constructor, when you run `bin/magento` it throws this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Laminas\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Laminas\\Service...')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Laminas\\Service...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Laminas\\Service...', NULL, 'serviceLocator', 'Magento\\Setup\\M...')
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument('Magento\\Setup\\M...', Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectMana in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 50
```

It seems to do this if you try adding any class in `Magento\Setup\...` as a dependency. It also happens if I try creating the InstallerFactory class using object manager directly instead of adding it as a dependency. Anyone know why?

Comment: I added a preference for `Laminas\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface` as `Laminas\ServiceManager\ServiceManager` and it fixes the issue, but it seems like it may cause problems.

There is another class inside vendor/lamina that also implements that same interface.

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason as per me is that that code or class InstallerFactory is in Setup and your code come under the module that's why it is getting skipped or unable to find it

Maybe I am wrong but I think this class is not getting used by magento2-modules

Comment: Hi Nilesh,

Thanks for the reply. I do think it has something to do with the fact that InstallerFactory is in the setup folder. 

I think this might be an autoload issue. It can find the path to the InstallerFactory class, but it can't find the location of the InstallerFactory's Laminas\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface dependency that it's complaining about.

Comment: yes agree - I do not have much knowledge but I think that autoloader is bound to find the class from a particular folder like app/code, generated/ vendor/ etc